# SQL get range of dates in between given dates grouped by another column in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, datediff

In this table -

```
----------------------------------------------
ID  | user   | type   | timestamp
----------------------------------------------
1   | 1      | 1      | 2019-02-08 15:00:00
2   | 1      | 3      | 2019-02-15 15:00:00
3   | 1      | 2      | 2019-03-06 15:00:00
4   | 2      | 3      | 2019-02-01 15:00:00
5   | 2      | 1      | 2019-02-06 15:00:00
6   | 3      | 1      | 2019-01-10 15:00:00
7   | 3      | 4      | 2019-02-08 15:00:00
8   | 3      | 3      | 2019-02-24 15:00:00
9   | 3      | 2      | 2019-03-04 15:00:00
10  | 3      | 3      | 2019-03-05 15:00:00
```

I need to find the number of days every user has been in a particular type in the given range of days.

Eg: For the given range **2019-02-01** to **2019-03-04**, the output should be

```
--------------------------------
user   | type   | No. of days
--------------------------------
1      | 1      | 7
1      | 3      | 17
2      | 3      | 6
3      | 1      | 29
2      | 4      | 16
2      | 3      | 8
```

The use can switch between types at any day but I need to capture all those switches and the number of days the user has been in a type. I currently solve this by getting all the values and filtering stuff manually in JS. Is there any way to do this by a SQL query? I use MYSQL 5.7.23.

EDIT:

The above output is incorrect but really appreciate everyone overlooking that and helping me with the right query. Here is the correct output for this question -

```
--------------------------------
user | type | No. of days
--------------------------------
   1 |    1 |          7
   1 |    3 |         19
   2 |    3 |          5
   3 |    1 |         29
   3 |    2 |          1
   3 |    3 |          8
   3 |    4 |         16
```

Comment: Could you specify how `No. of days` is being counted? In your example, why does user 3 only show up with type 1 when it looks like type 4, 3, and 2 are also relevant in this date range? And why is user 2, type 3 listed twice separately in your results?

Comment: That was a typo from my side. Sorry about that. Edited the question with the right output now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lead()` and then `datediff()` and `sum()` and a lot of date comparisons:

```
select user, type,
       sum(datediff( least(next_ts, '2019-03-04'), greatest(timestamp, '2019-02-01'))
from (select t.*,
             lead(timestamp, 1, '2019-03-04') over (partition by user order by timestamp) as next_ts
      from t
     ) t
where next_ts >= '2019-02-01' and
      timestamp <= '2019-03-04'
group by user, type;
```

EDIT:

In older versions, you can use:

```
select user, type,
       sum(datediff( least(next_ts, '2019-03-04'), greatest(timestamp, '2019-02-01'))
from (select t.*,
             (select coalesce(min(timestamp), '2019-03-04')
               from t t2
               where t2.user = t.user and t2.timestamp > t.timestamp
             ) as next_ts
      from t
     ) t
where next_ts >= '2019-02-01' and
      timestamp <= '2019-03-04'
group by user, type;
```

Comment: yes I don't think this will work in 5.7. Do you have a query for 5.7?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it in MysQL 5.7 and without user variables:

```
select 
    t.user,
    t.type,
    sum(datediff(
        greatest(tlead.timestamp, '2019-02-01'), 
        least(t.timestamp, '2019-03-04'))
    ) no_of_days
from mytable t
inner join mytable tlead 
    on  tlead.user = t.user
    and tlead.timestamp > t.timestamp
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from mytable t1
        where 
            t1.user = t.user 
            and t1.timestamp > t.timestamp
            and t1.timestamp < tlead.timestamp
    )
where tlead.timestamp >= '2019-02-01' and t.timestamp <= '2019-03-04'
group by t.user, t.type
order by t.user, t.type
```

This basically emulates `lead()` with a self-join and a `not exists` condition: table alias `tlead` is the *next* record for the same user. The rest is filtering, aggregating, and computing date differences within the target date range.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d81a2ca70ee5a37c9d3fdf3ebb4c94e5)** - results are not exactly the same as yours, but I suspect they are actually correct:

```
user | type | no_of_days
---: | ---: | ---------:
   1 |    1 |          7
   1 |    3 |         19
   2 |    3 |          5
   3 |    1 |         29
   3 |    2 |          1
   3 |    3 |          8
   3 |    4 |         16
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you want:

```
select id, user, type, time_stamp, (
    select datediff(min(time_stamp), t1.time_stamp)
    from table1 as t2
    where t2.user = t1.user 
    and   t2.time_stamp > t1.time_stamp
    ) as days
from table1 as t1
where 0 < (select count(*) from table1 as t3 where t3.user = t1.user
           and   t3.time_stamp > t1.time_stamp )
order by id;
```

Working in a fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/347ab5/26

If you also want the "final" row for each user use this variation:

```
select id, user, type, time_stamp, (
    select datediff(coalesce(min(time_stamp),current_timestamp()) , t1.time_stamp)
    from table1 as t2
    where t2.user = t1.user 
    and   t2.time_stamp > t1.time_stamp
    ) as days
from table1 as t1
order by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't get exactly as you wanted, but its accurate

```
SELECT 
  `user`
  ,`type`
  ,dategone `No. of days`
  FROM
(SELECT 
  `type`,
  IF(@id = `user`,DATEDIFF(`timestamp` , @days), -1) dategone #
  ,@id := `user`  `user`
  ,@days := `timestamp` 
 FROM
   (SELECT 
      `D`, `user`, `type`, `timestamp`
    From table1
    ORDER BY `user` ASC, `timestamp`  ASC) a
   , (SELECT @days :=0) b, (SELECT @id :=0) c) d
WHERE dategone > -1;
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `D` INTEGER,
>   `user` INTEGER,
>   `type` INTEGER,
>   `timestamp` VARCHAR(19)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`D`, `user`, `type`, `timestamp`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1', '1', '2019-02-08 15:00:00'),
>   ('2', '1', '3', '2019-02-15 15:00:00'),
>   ('3', '1', '2', '2019-03-06 15:00:00'),
>   ('4', '2', '3', '2019-02-01 15:00:00'),
>   ('5', '2', '1', '2019-02-06 15:00:00'),
>   ('6', '3', '1', '2019-01-10 15:00:00'),
>   ('7', '3', '4', '2019-02-08 15:00:00'),
>   ('8', '3', '3', '2019-02-24 15:00:00'),
>   ('9', '3', '2', '2019-03-04 15:00:00'),
>   ('10', '3', '3', '2019-03-05 15:00:00');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   `user`
>   ,`type`
>   ,dategone `No. of days`
>   FROM
> (SELECT 
> `type`,
> IF(@id = `user`,DATEDIFF(`timestamp` , @days), -1) dategone #
> ,@id := `user`  `user`
> ,@days := `timestamp` 
> FROM
> (SELECT 
>   `D`, `user`, `type`, `timestamp`
> From table1
> ORDER BY `user` ASC, `timestamp`  ASC) a, (SELECT @days :=0) b, (SELECT @id :=0) c) d
> WHERE dategone > -1;
> ```
>
> ```
> user | type | No. of days
> ---: | ---: | ----------:
>    1 |    3 |           7
>    1 |    2 |          19
>    2 |    1 |           5
>    3 |    4 |          29
>    3 |    3 |          16
>    3 |    2 |           8
>    3 |    3 |           1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b17501b42e8d484c4b5016cbd2326710)*